# Form Submit clears values before passing data to server-side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, validation

There are couple of Javascript functions that validate the values for the two fields in question.

The functions are doing the job intended but when I submit the form, the two values validated by said functions are blank

here is the js code

```
<script>
        function updateRequirements() {
            var contract = document.getElementById("contract").value;
            var expdate = document.getElementById("expdate");
            console.log(contract);
            if (contract == "YES") {
                expdate.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                expdate.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function dateRequirements() {
            var contract = document.getElementById("contract").value;
            var expdate = document.getElementById("expdate")
            var expdateValue = expdate.value;
            console.log(expdateValue);
            if (contract == "YES") {
                var today = new Date();
                var exp = new Date(expdateValue);
                var difference = exp - today;                
                if (difference > 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
                    alert("The expiration date cannot be more than 365 days from today");
                    expdate.value = "";  // Clear the date field
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Here is short version of the form:

```
    [![<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="EntryADFormModel.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EntryADFormModel.FirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EntryADFormModel.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="EntryADFormModel.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EntryADFormModel.LastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EntryADFormModel.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="EntryADFormModel.Contractor" class="control-label"></label>
            <select name="contract" class="form-control" asp-for="EntryADFormModel.Contractor" id="contract" onchange="updateRequirements();">
                <option value="SELECT" selected disabled>Select Answer</option>
                <option value="YES">Yes</option>
                <option value="NO">No</option>
                
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="EntryADFormModel.Contractor" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="EntryADFormModel.AccountExpDate" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EntryADFormModel.AccountExpDate" class="form-control" id="expdate" name="expdate" onchange="dateRequirements()" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EntryADFormModel.AccountExpDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>]
```

Here is the form with missing values after being submitted
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag helper `asp-for` will dynamically generate the id and name attribute, but if you specify the name attribute in the html, the tag helper default generated name value will be overrided.
[image]

And your backend binds the model by name attribute, it needs name like: `EntryADFormModel.PropertyName`.

For your scenario, **just remove the name attribute** like below:

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="EntryADFormModel.Contractor" id="contract" onchange="updateRequirements();">
    <option value="SELECT" selected disabled>Select Answer</option>
    <option value="YES">Yes</option>
    <option value="NO">No</option>
                
</select>

<input asp-for="EntryADFormModel.AccountExpDate" class="form-control" id="expdate" onchange="dateRequirements()" />
```